# Xcode instruments is showing leaks in attached image. How can i fix them?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, xcode-instruments

Xcode instruments is showing that highlighted lines are leaking memory. But i don't know how to fix them. I can use CGImageRelease(shadowImageRef). But how to fix [shadowImageLeft drawAtPoint:...] leaks.

Here is the link to code file: 
https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/blob/master/src/ios/GoogleMaps/GoogleMapsViewController.m

Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It will be a lot easier to offer help if you also copy and paste the actual code as text into your question. Please be sure it is formatted properly.

Comment: @rmaddy i have updated question with link to code file.

Comment: No, copy and paste the relevant code into your question.

Comment: Issue fixed, Switched to multiple_maps branch of google maps plugin. Thanks @rmaddy.